Correcting Pronunciation Mistakes While Praying
I was praying and during Surah Al-Fatiha, I made a mistake in the recitation of the ayah:
"صراط الذين أنعمت عليهم"
I accidentally pronounced the "ه" (ha) in "عليهم" (alayhim) as "ح" (ḥa). I realized this mistake immediately, but I thought it didn't change the meaning, so I continued without correcting it and went on to the next ayah.
Later, I started worrying that maybe I should have corrected it right then and there.
Here are my concerns:

I wasn't sure if I was supposed to go back and correct the mistake immediately after I realized it.

I didn’t know that I had to correct it within the same rak'ah, because at the time, I thought it wasn’t necessary. I just continued my prayer as usual.

I realized the mistake while still in the same rak'ah, but I didn't correct it because I didn’t know that was required. Now I’m not sure if my prayer was valid.

Does this mistake, which didn’t change the meaning in my understanding, invalidate my prayer if I didn’t correct it, or is it forgiven because I didn’t know better at the time?


I’m looking for guidance on whether my prayer is valid and what I should do in the future when I realize mistakes in my recitation during prayer.

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
